# Time limit exceed error when using a list but works when using set for Leetcode problem in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, linked-list, set

I am solving a leetcode problem to find the intersection point in a linkedlist. When I use the list it gives me time limit exceed error but when I use set it gives me the answer. As each node in LinkedList is different both set and list would have the same element

Below is my code

```
def getIntersectionNode(self, headA: ListNode, headB: ListNode):
        nodes = set()
        while headA != None:
            nodes.add(headA)
            headA = headA.next

        while headB != None:
            if headB in nodes:
                return headB
            headB = headB.next
        return None
```

What is the reason for error to occur when using list instead of set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `in` operator is implemented differently for a set and a list.

- For a list, the code must iterate over the entire list to check each element, potentially a linear-time operation.
- For a set, the code checks if a given element is present using its hash code in constant time (on average).

Suppose A has *m* nodes and B has *n* nodes, and the lists don't intersect (worst-case scenario). If `nodes` is a list, the algorithm will have to iterate over all the nodes of A *for each* node in B, giving a time complexity of Θ(*m*×*n*).  By contrast, when using a set the time complexity will be Θ(*m*+*n*).  For large values of *m* and *n*, this makes a big difference in the runtime of the function.

Here are some references on how hash tables (the basis for Python's `set` and `dict` data structures) work:

- https://towardsdatascience.com/hash-tables-explained-5dc457db50da?gi=6cce0c91f791
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table

Comment: @AjinkyaGadgil You're welcome!  If this answered your question you can click the "check mark" next to the answer to mark the question as solved.

Comment: I have one question though. How exactly the set checks in a larger list?

Comment: That's a complicated question to answer, I'll add a reference in my answer so you can read about how hash tables work.

Comment: Thanks. I will check the links.

Answer (score 1):

In python sets are faster for checking if they contain a certain element.
The following will be faster if `nodes` is a set.

```
if headB in nodes:
```

But for example iterating over a set would be slower than iterating over a list.